# "Deprecated function: implode()" on GMap Drupal module

Tags: 7

I have containerised a legacy Drupal 7 website with Docker. This is the docker-compose file:

```
version: '2.0'
services:
    drupal:
        build: .
        ports:
         - "8080:80"
        links:
         - mysql:mysql
    mysql:
        build: ./db
        ports:
         - "6603:3306"
```

The `drupal` container uses the official `drupal:7.72` image, whereas `mysql` stems from `mysql:5`. The database container is responsive and reachable from the Drupal container. The main page of the website loads correctly, but it shows this error message:

> Deprecated function: implode(): Passing glue string after array is
> deprecated. Swap the parameters in
> Drupal\gmap\GmapDefaults->__construct() (line 107 of
> /var/www/html/sites/all/modules/gmap/lib/Drupal/gmap/GmapDefaults.php).

There is [a similar error](https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal/issues/3098164) reported for a different function in Drupal 7.70. But apparently it was resolved with 7.71.

How can this particular error be solved? Would editing the `GmapDefaults.php` file be an option?

Comment: All of the information about docker/databases doesn't sound relevant. It's simply because you're using PHP7.4+ and the order of the variables for the PHP implode function changed (https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php). See if there's a module update for the gmap module that fixes this or if there is a patch available in the issue queue. If there isn't then yes editing GmapDefaults.php would be the only way to stop the notice

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's a [known bug](https://www.drupal.org/project/gmap/issues/3118279) for the gmap module that is been tracked and has been fixed already on drupal.org. Just apply the patch.

Comment: @Leigh – Hacking a module never should be an option. If there's no patch yet it should be created and then applied. You also can apply local patches easily with Composer if contribution is no option.

Comment: @leymannx I never specifically said change the file and forget about it. Regardless if you change the file in notepad and save, create a patch or any other method the answer is the same, the file needs to be edited. The best practice for that is a separate question with many previous answers/google search results. But yeah flagging it up is probably worth while

Comment: @leymannx Since you produced an answer, I would rather have it filed in as such than close the question. The docker information is relevant since it determines the versions of the software in use.

Comment: @leymannx The patch you pointed to seems to be encoded for MSDOS. However, all docker images involved are based on Linux systems. I would be thankful if you could point to a patch for Linux.

Comment: I'd prefer you either reencode the patch yourself if that really is the problem you have (I doubt that but I don't have any info about how you actually tried to apply the patch) or simply create a new one yourself since it contains only a few lines of code.

Answer (score 3):

This answer draws upon the [comments above](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/296260/deprecated-function-implode?noredirect=1#comment375072_296260) by [leymannx](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/users/15055/leymannx). The essential problem is an incompatibility between the GMap module and PHP 7.4, for which [a patch is available](https://www.drupal.org/project/gmap/issues/3118279). In this answer the patch is applied to the code repository itself, prior to any Docker builds, this is possibly the cleanest method.

The first step is to download the patch into the right folder in the repository:

```
cd sites/all/modules/gmap
wget https://www.drupal.org/files/issues/2020-03-06/gmap-php7.4.patch
```

The patch file is encoded for MSDOS, therefore it must be converted before the patch can be applied. Here all the target files are converted too, as a precaution:

```
dos2unix ./gmap-php7.4.patch
dos2unix gmap_test/gmap_test.features.inc
dos2unix lib/Drupal/gmap/GmapDefaults.php
dos2unix tests/inc/gmap_defaults.inc
```

The patch can now be applied. Since this is a git repository, the `git` command itself can not be used.

```
patch -p1 -i ./gmap-php7.4.patch
```

Finally remove all the extra files the process may have created. They are not needed in the container.

```
rm *.patch gmap_test/gmap_test.features.inc.orig lib/Drupal/gmap/GmapDefaults.php.orig tests/inc/gmap_defaults.inc.orig
```